# @googlemaps with AdvancedMarkerElement markers bugging after leaving the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

When opening the page where the map is, everything works fine but if I switch to some other page and go back to where the map markers are breaking and I get this error in console:[image]

Here is the code, it looks like the error is occuring when I am trying to use .AdvancedMarkerElement which is essential for what I need to build

```
const addMarkers = (map) => {
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
const customMarker = document.createElement('div')
customMarker.className = 'test'
const markers = trees.map(([name, lat, lng]) => {
  const content = document.createElement('div')
  const imageContent = document.createElement('img')
  const text = document.createElement('p')
  text.innerText = 'John Smith'
  content.className = 'marker'
  imageContent.className = 'marker-image'
  imageContent.src =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1687161590608-6d948d357bad?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=706&q=80'
  content.appendChild(imageContent)
  content.appendChild(text)

  const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    position: { lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) },
    map,
    content,
  })

  marker.addListener('click', () => {
    infoWindow.setPosition({ lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) })
    infoWindow.setContent(`
      <div class="info-window">
        <div class='image-container'>
          <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1687161590608-6d948d357bad?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=706&q=80' alt='task-image' />
        </div>
        <div class='data-container'>
          <h3>John Smith</h3>
          <p>Pool Cleaning</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    `)
    infoWindow.open({ map })
  })

  return marker
})

new MarkerClusterer({
  markers,
  map,
  algorithm: new SuperClusterAlgorithm({ radius: 200 }),
})
```

}

Comment: Hi, do you have a codesandbox or jsfiddle example of this issue? I'd be happy to take a look for you.

Comment: @jeantimex this issue is long gone, I don't quite remember how exactly I managed to solve it but the problem was that something from google maps was being imported once again when I was returning to the page and breaking everything . Anyways, now I removed react-google-maps library and just used plain google maps javascript api and its ok now